# Setting state of a 'Loading' boolean in react doesn't update

Tags: reactjs, setstate, use-state

I have a page which allows a user to submit a url from which data is scraped. The user is subsequently presented with the filtered data.

Because the scraping takes some time I would like to implement a loader. While the loader class will (hopefully) be relatively straight forward, it's the state for `loading` which I'm having issues with. The state itself is never updated. Although other state values are such as `setFilters`.

### Body.js

```
const [searchState, setSearchState] = useState({
  searchCriteria: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Central_Vietnam_floods",
  headers:[],
  references: []
});

const [filterState, setFilters] = useState({
  languageFilter: ""
});

const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState({
  loading: false
});
```

The above are all passed into `Search` with a context

```
<>
  <SearchContext.Provider value={{searchState, setSearchState,filterState, setFilters, loadingState, setLoadingState}} >
      <Search />
      <DonateButton />
      <WikiHeaderGroup />
  </SearchContext.Provider>
</>
```

And then I have a `handleSubmit` inside the `Search` component.

### Search.js

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import {SearchContext} from "../../contexts/SearchContext"
import "../../App.css"

export function Search (){

  const {searchState, setSearchState, filterState, setFilters, loadingState, setLoadingState} = useContext(SearchContext);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      setFilters({languageFilter:""})
      setLoadingState({loading:true})
      console.log("Loading State : " + loadingState.loading)

      event.preventDefault();
      event.persist();            //persists the event object into the function

      const fetchReferences = async () => {

        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/search/', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            url: searchState.searchCriteria
            }),
          headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}

        }).then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                return response.json()

        }).then(json => {
          console.log(json)
          setSearchState({
            headers:json.headers,
            references:json.references
          })
          setLoadingState({loading:false})
          console.log("Loading State : " + loadingState.loading)
    });}

      fetchReferences();
  }

    return (
      <div className="search container">
        <div className="input-group input-group-sm mb-3 center">
          <div className="input-group-prepend">
            <span className="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Wikipedia URL:</span>
          </div>

          <form onSubmit={(event) => handleSubmit(event)}>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="searchBox"
            className="form-control center"
            aria-label="Sizing example input"
            aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
            value={searchState.searchCriteria}
            onChange={(event) => setSearchState({searchCriteria:event.target.value, resultId:0})}
            placeholder="Add a url" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );

}
export default Search;
```

Comment: can you show me how u access the context? there is no code about that

Comment: can you add a comment of where "it is not updating" and how are you using it to display your "loading" message

Comment: I'm using a console.log to check the value of `loadingState.loading`. This always comes out to false in the console output. I'm justing adding the code showing access to the context now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use object for booleans, just

```
const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState(false);
....
setLoadingState(true)
```

btw looks like a closure problem. you see loadingState always false cause the closure.
take a look at this [Be Aware of Stale Closures when Using React Hooks](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/)

A way to solve it is using refs

```
const loadingStateRef = useRef(loadingState);
//then inside the function u can access 
latestValue.current
```

Comment: How do you then obtain loadingState? Is it `loadingState` on its own or does one need to use `loadingState.value` or similar.